# {status: "error", error: "Duplicate email"} with MERN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to redirect the register page to the login page but I am getting a duplicate email error when registering a new user, therefore it is not redirecting to login page. The credentials are not getting stored due to this error I believe.
I must've made an error in the register file

### Register.js

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
function App() {
    const navigate= useNavigate()

    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    async function registerUser(event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name,
                email,
                password,
            }),
        })

        const data = await response.json()

        if (data.status === 'ok') {
            navigate.push('/login')
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <form onSubmit={registerUser}>
                <input
                    value={name}
                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Name"
                />
                <br />
                <input
                    value={email}
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="Email"
                />
                <br />
                <input
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Register" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

### server index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const User = require('./models/user.model')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const { response } = require('express')

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/TechGenius')

app.post('/api/register', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    try {
        await User.create({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
        })
        res.json({ status: 'ok' })
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ status: 'error', error: 'Duplicate email' })
    }
})

app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({
        email: req.body.email,
    })

    if (!user) {
        return { status: 'error', error: 'Invalid login' }
    }

    const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(
        req.body.password,
        user.password
    )

    if (isPasswordValid) {
        const token = jwt.sign(
            {
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
            },
            'secret123'
        )
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)

        return res.json({ status: 'ok', user: token })
    } else {
        return res.json({ status: 'error', user: false })
    }
})

app.get('/api/quote', async (req, res) => {
    const token = req.headers['x-access-token']

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'secret123')
        const email = decoded.email
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: email })

        return res.json({ status: 'ok', quote: user.quote })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.json({ status: 'error', error: 'invalid token' })
    }
})

app.post('/api/quote', async (req, res) => {
    const token = req.headers['x-access-token']

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'secret123')
        const email = decoded.email
        await User.updateOne(
            { email: email },
            { $set: { quote: req.body.quote } }
        )

        return res.json({ status: 'ok' })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.json({ status: 'error', error: 'invalid token' })
    }
})

app.listen(1337, () => {
    console.log('Server started on 1337')
})
```

### user.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const User = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        password: { type: String, required: true },
        quote: { type: String },
    },
    { collection: 'user-data' }
)

const model = mongoose.model('UserData', User)

module.exports = model
```

Answer (score 0):

On you model, you stated that User model consist of `name`, `email`, `password` and `quote`, in which all of them are required except `quote`.

But on your Register function, you only pass `name` and `email`, not including `password`. You hardcode the error on your catch method to `Duplicate email`, that's why it always said `Duplicate email`. You could try to `console.log()` the `error` on your catch and I'm sure it will say that password is a required field.

```js
app.post('/api/register', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    try {
        await User.create({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        })
        res.json({ status: 'ok' })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.json({ status: 'error', error: err.message })
    }
})
```